# Python3: Importing Function dependent on Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Good day! So I'm trying to have a frequently used function in its own file for organizational purposes, and would like to be able to import it when needed.

```
#Plotting fits image function
def plotfits(subsize,title,imgdata,color,cbarlabel):
    plt.subplot(subsize)
    plt.title(titSle)
    plt.imshow(imgdata, cmap=color)
    ibar1 = plt.colorbar()
    ibar1.set_label(cbarlabel)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

Then when I try `from plotfits import plotfits` in my main file where I would like to use the function, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jorge/python/heliotutorial/tut01_new.py", line 39, in <module>
    plotfits(221,'Intensity',imgdata1,'gray','Continuum Intensity')
  File "/home/jorge/python/heliotutorial/plotfits.py", line 4, in plotfits
    def plotfits(subsize,title,imgdata,color,cbarlabel):
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

But I already have pyplot imported with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I thought maybe I would have to import pyplot inside the function again for it to work, as then it'd be defined inside the function:

```
def plotfits(subsize,title,imgdata,color,cbarlabel):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ....
```

But this does not work, nor does having the import statement at the beginning of the file. What could be my mistake here? (Function does work if written and defined inside the main file)

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Explain "This does not work either." What's wrong with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the start of the new file containing the function?

Comment: Doesn't work either, I get the same error. I think there must be some sort of logic mistake due to the fact it's a function made out of another function.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], so we can copy and paste your code to run it directly. As it stands, there's not enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as there is still no [mcve] available.